# Navigate from MainView to another View

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am new to WPF and i am using `WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit 0.1` to get my hands on WPF.

I have a fairly simple question but i cant get my head around it.

How do i display new view from the menu item on the mainview?

This is how my code looks like:

MainView.xaml

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
   <MenuItem Header="_File">
      <MenuItem Command="{Binding NewPage}" Header="New Page" 
                                   InputGestureText="Ctrl-N" />
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
private DelegateCommand newPageCommand;

    public ICommand NewPage
    {

        get
        {

            if (newPageCommand == null)
            {
                newPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoToNewPage);
            }
            return newPageCommand;
        }
    }


    private void GoToNewPage()
    {
      ???
    }
```

What do i write in the GoToNewPage to display the newPage.xaml?

Comment: what is a page, a dialog, a window or something like a tabitem?

Comment: its a new wpfPage. newpage.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your application is run entirely in the ViewModels, and Views are used to allow users to interact with the ViewModels in a friendly manner.

In your case, the ViewModel might have a property called `CurrentPage`, which is bound to a `ContentControl.Content` in your View. To change pages, the `GoToNewPage` command would set the `CurrentPage` property to a `NewPageViewModel`.

This would cause the `ContentControl` to realize it's binding has changed, and in the process of updating the binding, it would realize that the `Content` has changed and it needs to use a new `DataTemplate` to draw that content.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomePageViewModel}">
            <local:HomePageView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NewPageViewModel}">
            <local:NewPageView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

I have a simple example of this [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) if you're interested

Comment: it says 'local' is an undeclared namespace. Any idea what am i missing here?

Comment: @asdfg You need to define the `local` namespace at the top of your code. The sample code shown assumes that both the `Views` and the `ViewModels` are in the same namespace, and that namespace is mapped to `local` with `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`

Comment: One of the many, many reasons for using Resharper is that if you reference a type in XAML without providing its (XML) namespace, it will propose a namespace for you, and even go so far as to create a new namespace declaration and prefix if one is needed.